# Why is it not ideal to import react-bootstrap using destructuring

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-bootstrap

The documentation page suggests to only import the components needed. There are 2 examples given here https://react-bootstrap.netlify.com/getting-started/introduction#importing:

```
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Button';

// or less ideally
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

What makes the 2nd method 'less ideal'?

Comment: Take a look at this. https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/2683 may give you some insight.

Comment: According to the ticket, that 2nd method will have to import the whole library, but only make Button available. Thanks for a quick reply!

Comment: If you're using webpack then treeshaking will take care of it

Comment: I am using webpack, but that ticket suggests that the tree-shaking itself is broken somehow.

Comment: You cannot possibly rely on webpack's treeshaking as that depends on marking all your code as `sideeffect-free` which is hardly possible.

Comment: as aside this syntax `import {Button} from "somewhere"` is not actually destructuring, but is rather a named import.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first case you are only importing the code for that particular component.

In the second case you are importing the whole library and inserting only a particular component into the current scope.